# Angularjs: Watching Elements For Changes in ng-active/ng-inactive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to know the most "angular" way to watch an element for visibly.

An example use case is dynamic form resizing based on the number of ngMessages that are active.

ngMessages use ng-in/active to control their visibility:

```
<!-- class="ng-inactive" is added by angular when the page loads-->
<div ng-messages="formToValidate.fieldName.$error" role="alert" class="ng-inactive">
.
.  <div ng-message="...">list of messages<div>
.
</div>
```

So the question is: what is the best way to watch watch this element and run some logic when a new message is active?

I know that I could use something in the controller like:

```
$scope.$watch('formToValidate.fieldName.$error', () => {

    if ($scope.formToValidate.fieldName.$invalid) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...         
    }

}, true);
```

But I don't know if there is something more concise such as a smart `ng-watch`, and I would prefer the logic tied to the message element's visibility rather than the presence of an error.

Is there a better way I do not know about?

Thanks.

Comment: One way to approach it would be to create a directive that watches the content of `ng-messages` or any other desired attribute; That said, I consider your approach valid